# MySQL statement with invalid data in WHERE clause returns 0 rows instead of failing

Tags: mysql

Hopefully this is a simple question.  I have the following table:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| KEY_COL | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| COL2    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

When I do an update on the table using invalid values in the where clause for KEY_COL, it completes successfully and returns 0 rows affected:

```
mysql> update LGSRV_TAB_DOC set COL2='9' where KEY_COL='A';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I have my sql_mode set to STRICT_ALL_TABLES, so I was expecting the update to fail since I'm supplying an invalid value for KEY_COL ('A' instead of a numeric).  Is there any way I can change this behavior so that the update fails with an error?  I'm running version 8.0.11 on RHEL 6.9.

Comment: Strict mode only prevents an attempt to store an invalid value into a column, it doesn't apply when comparing.

Comment: E.g. try `update LGSRV_TAB_DOC set COL2='A' where KEY_COL=1;`

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no way to cause MySQL to return an error when comparing an invalid type?  I'm just a little surprised because that's not how it works on just about every other database I've dealt with.

Comment: MySQL is notoriously forgiving about things like this, similar in philosophy to JavaScript and PHP loose comparisons.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, good to know.  I'll try to remember that going forward.